# Is there a way to chek for foreign keys in MySql query browser?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How do i check if there is a foreign key between two tables in MySql Query browser?
The reason i need it, is because in order for Mysql Workbench to create a model containing all the connections, is through foreign keys, however, it shows no foreign key in any table.

So i'm left here wondering if the database was really built without any foreign keys (Which is actually possible) or if i'm doing something wrong. That's why i want to check in the Query browser.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a Foreign Keys tab which should allow you to set or change the relationships.You can use this link to do this. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-foreign-keys-tab.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial here which should help you: http://jetgrill.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-add-foreign-key-in-mysql-query.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query database metadata using the **information schema**.
**Constraints** can be queried using

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

You can add a where-clause to limit the result to the tables or relations you're interested in (`TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, ...`)